# Mistake while computing residue of Dedekind Zeta function

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I want to calculate the following limit:
$$\lim_{s \to 1^+} (s-1)\zeta_K(s)  $$ where $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ with Dedekind Zeta function of it, $\zeta_K(s)$. We know that $\zeta_K(s)$ has a simple pole at $1$ and its residue can be found by class number formula given by $\cfrac{2^{r_1}(2\pi)^{r_2}Rh}{m\sqrt{(|\Delta)|}}$ where $r_1$ is the number of real embeddings of the field, $r_2$ for complex -*nonconjugate*- ones; $R$ for the regulator of $K, h$ is the class number of $K$, $m$ is the number of roots of unity in $K$ and $\Delta$ is the discriminant of $K$.

So, we have $r_1 =0, r_2 =1$. I found that $R$ is equal to $1$. $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is PID so $h=1$. $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ has $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$ as roots of unity so $m=4$ and finally $\Delta  =-4$. Writing it all up, we get:
$$\cfrac{2^{0}.(2\pi)^{1}.1.1}{4\sqrt{(|-4)|}} = \cfrac{\pi}{4}$$.

On the other hand, I define another function $Z(s)=\displaystyle\sum_{x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^{>0}}\cfrac{1}{(x^2 + y^2)^s}$.

After few manipulation, I bounded $(s-1)Z(s)$ above and below with "usual" $\zeta$-function and concluded that $ \cfrac{1}{4} \le \lim_{s \to  1^+}(s-1)Z(s) \le 1$. With the help of a theorem, which I can state it in the comments if necessary,  $\lim_{s \to  1^+}(s-1)Z(s)$ is actually $\cfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Now, here comes the my question:
$\displaystyle\zeta_K(s) = \sum_{0 \ne I \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K} \cfrac{1}{N(I)^s}$ $K$ is PID so every ideal $I$ is of the form $(a+ bi)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, we actually have
$$\displaystyle\zeta_K(s) = \sum_{0 \ne I \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K} \cfrac{1}{N(I)^s}= \sum_{a,b \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}} \cfrac{1}{N(a+bi)^s}=\sum_{a,b \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}} \cfrac{1}{(a^2 +b^2)^s}$$.

It looks quite similar to our first function $Z(s)=\displaystyle\sum_{x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^{>0}}\cfrac{1}{(x^2 + y^2)^s}$ with some difference, we are now summing over all integers, not the ones in the first quadrant. Therefore, I am expecting that I should get $Res_{s=1}(\zeta_K(s)) = 4 \times Res_{s=1}(Z(s)) = 4 \times \cfrac{\pi}{4} = \pi$. However, in the beginning, we found that $Res_{s=1}(\zeta_K(s)) = \cfrac{\pi}{4}$.

So, what am I missing, what do I wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write
$$\zeta_K(s)=\cdots=\sum_{a,b\in\Bbb Z-\{0\}}\frac1{(a^2+b^2)^s}.$$
But this isn't the case. Each nonzero ideal is $(a+bi)$ for four
different $(a,b)\in\Bbb Z^2-\{(0,0)\}$, since $\Bbb Z[i]$ has four units,
so
$$\zeta_K(s)=\frac14\sum_{a,b\in\Bbb Z-\{0\}}\frac1{(a^2+b^2)^s}.$$

Comment: You mean we have four units $1,-1,i,-i$ so associate elements generate the same ideal for example $<a+bi> = (-i)<a+bi>$, right? Therefore "we should not count $(-a,b)$ if we already count $(a,b)$". Am I correct?

Comment: @Ninja exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID with finite unit group then $$\zeta_K(s) = \sum_{I \subset \mathcal{O}_K} N(I)^{-s}=\frac{1}{|\mathcal{O}_K^\times|} \sum_{a \in \mathcal{O}_K \setminus \{0\}} N(a)^{-s}$$
Also
$$\lim_{s \to 1}(s-1)\sum_{a \in \mathcal{O}_K \setminus \{0\}} N(a)^{-s}\\ = \lim_{s \to 1}(s-1) \int_{\mathbb{R}^2, \|x\| > 1} \|x\|^{-2s}dx\\+\sum_{a \in \mathcal{O}_K \setminus \{0\}} (N(a)^{-s}-\int_{[0,1]^2} \|x+(\Re(a),\Im(a))\|^{-2s}1_{\|x+(\Re(a),\Im(a))\| < 1}dx)$$
$$=\lim_{s \to 1}(s-1) \int_{\mathbb{R}^2, \|x\| > 1} \|x\|^{-2s}dx = \pi$$
To understand $\cfrac{2^{r_1}(2\pi)^{r_2}Rh}{m\sqrt{(|\Delta)|}}$ you need to look at the associated theta function $\sum_{a \in \mathcal{O}_K} e^{-\pi \sum_{j} |\sigma_j(a)|^2 x_j}$ where $\sigma$ are the complex and real embeddings

Comment: Well, unfortunately I could not understand second equality, the integral part.     Also, is the norm usual Euclidean norm?

Comment: @Ninja $\int_1^\infty (\lfloor x \rfloor^{-s} - x^{-s})dx$ converges at $s=1$. It is the same in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: It may take a while for me to understand this correctly.  I am not familiar with theta functions so can you suggest any  reference for related theta arguments, please?

Comment: @Ninja Did you prove the functional equation for $\zeta(s)$ and Dirichlet L-functions ? Then of Dedekind zeta functions of quadratic imaginary fields, then of general number fields, then of Hecke L-functions..

Comment: I have not actually, I better check them first then.

Comment: Of course there are also modular forms involved. The point is to prove the prime number theorem for all those things, studying their Riemann hypothesis and their rich analytic, arithmetic and algebraic properties, proving the Fermat last theorem by applying it to elliptic curves.

Comment: By the way, after my realisation, the first equality seems very meaningful. However, I have not seen it in a lecture note or a book. Can refer some lecture notes/books which states it? I guess it should have more fruitful stuff to learn.

Comment: @Ninja told you the keyword is "functional equation of Dedekind zeta function". Personnally I spent a few days just on $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ (the simplest non PID case) and sage/magma

Comment: Okay, one last question about Magma, then:
How can I return just $r_1$ (or $r_2$) using Signature(K)? It returns $r_1$ and $r_2$, the output is not an array or set. So Signature(K)[1] is meaningless. What should I do?

Comment: @Ninja `P<x> := PolynomialRing(Integers()); K := NumberField(x^2-5); r_1,r_2 := Signature(K);` works fine http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ number of real embeddings , number of complex embeddings/2 so $n = r_1+2r_2$

Comment: Thank you for all your valuable comments. Have a nice day!